# Whenever my JVM ( of SOA server ) crosses 75% , how do i trigger a java thread dump

Tags: weblogic, soa, wlst

We observe the soa java process consuming a lot of cpu . it crosses to 75% many a times . I want some wlst or shell scripts which can be  run to get the heap dump whenever JVM crosses 75% .

Answer (score 0):

I had used this tutorial and put these in a shell script , this should help you
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384926